# Define spaceship operator for simple struct

Tags: c++, spaceship-operator

I am trying to explicitly implement the spaceship operator.

The following is a simple example which fails. What am I doing wrong? [godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/MPcfao4or)

```
#include <iostream>

struct Foo {
    int value;

    // both work
    auto operator<=>(const Foo&) const = default;
    //bool operator==(const Foo other) const { return value == other.value; }

    // both fail
    // auto operator<=>(const Foo& other) const { return value <=> other.value; }
    // auto operator<=>(const Foo other) const { return value <=> other.value; }
};

// fails
//auto operator<=>(const Foo lhs, const Foo rhs) { return lhs.value <=> rhs.value; }

int main(){
    Foo x{0};
    std::cout << (x == x) << '\n';
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `fails`.

Comment: @tkausl Compile time errors (super long obviously ;) ). See godbolt link.

Comment: I looked that link to Matt Godbolt's website, and there were no compile time errors there.

Comment: You need to comment both implementations of the "work" section and uncomment any one of the "fail" implementations.

Comment: When the code defines a non-`=default`-ed `operator<=>`, it forgot to provide an explicit `operator==`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`operator<=>` does not actually implement the `==` operator. `operator==` must be defined separately from `operator<=>`. So, you need to define `operator==` as well.

The reason is that it's quite often possible to implement `==` more efficiently than `<=>`.

Comment: Just to be perfectly clear, `operator<=>(...) = default` *does* declare a default `operator==` as well. But an explicit implementation of `operator<=>` does not provide an `operator==`. That's why OP's `default` example works, despite never implementing `operator==` for their class. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_comparisons

Comment: Thank you both! @SilvioMayolo this made the answer even clearer.

Comment: _"If operator<=> is defaulted and operator== is not declared at all, then operator== is implicitly defaulted."_

Comment: @Sam Varshavchik can you please fix your answer

Answer (score 2):

As per @Silvio Mayolo's link: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_comparisons

> If operator<=> is defaulted and operator== is not declared at all, then operator== is implicitly defaulted.

Therefore in this definition:

> `auto operator<=>(const Foo& other) const { return value <=> other.value; }`

`operator==` won't be implicitly declared, hence the compiler error.